# Problem with differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm doing some studying for a test and I have a question about differential equations. So we have this one exercise which says: $u_x=u_y$ (where subindices indicate partial derivative with respect the written variable) and $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$

I do what I've got to do and find that $X(x) = Ae^{lx}$ and $Y(y) = Be^{ly}$ so
$u(x,y) = ABe^{l(x+y)}$. The next exercise says that $u_{xx} = u_t$ so I do $X''(x)/X(x) = T'(t)/T(t)$. I solve this equation and I get $$X(x) = c_1e^{\sqrt{l}x} + c_2e^{-\sqrt{l}x}$$
and $T(t)  = Ae^{lt}$ but in the book $T(t) = e^{lt}$. So why doesn't it have a constant in front of $e^{lt}$? I find to by solving this equation: $T'(t) - lT(t) = 0$.

Comment: Because X(x) already contains a multiplicative constant (multiply c1 and c2 by a given parameter) so it is not useful to plug another one in T(t) since only the product X(x)T(t) is meaningful. Thus, to write T(t)=c3e^(lt) is not false, just useless.

Comment: I've added LaTeX formatting to your question, captain - apologies if I changed your intended meaning (it was tough to tell whether you wanted $\sqrt{l}\cdot x$ or $\sqrt{lx}$, for example).

Comment: What do $ux=uy$ and $u_{xx}=ut$ mean?